# Spring Boot Security - IllegalStateException:Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I was trying to configure the roles of the users using SpringBoot as backend, my `configure` method is defined like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.httpBasic().disable().csrf().disable().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/autenticacion/login", "/api/autenticacion/registro", "usuario/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/usuario/**").hasAuthority("ADMINISTRADOR").anyRequest().authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMINISTRADOR", "USUARIO").anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
        .disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint());
    }
```

The error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest

Is there something wrong with the notation or any other method I shouldn't be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue:

1. csrf() and anyRequest() appears twice.
2. .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMINISTRADOR", "USUARIO") is conflicted with others and should be removed

I change your code as below.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/autenticacion/login", "/api/autenticacion/registro", "usuario/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/usuario/**").hasAuthority("ADMINISTRADOR")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint());
}
```